# How to handle offscreen EGLContext properly on linux when doing massive rendering task?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, opengl, gpu, egl

Here's my situation, I'm working on a video rendering engine that runs on GPU cloud servers with Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit OS.

The engine listens to user requests, when it receive a rendering request, it will start a thread, create a `pbuffer EGLContext`, rendering the video frames using opengl calls, encoding frames to a video file, and then destroy the EGLContext. When multiple rendering requests received, rendering engine will start multiple threads and run multiple tasks in parallel. By the way, I set up and destroy `EGLContext` object using code from this [nvidia post](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/egl-eye-opengl-visualization-without-x-server/).
The thing is, after a lot of rendering tasks, render engine will crash randomly when calling `eglCreateContext`, it happens for both nVidia cards and ATI cards. And I don't know is it because I'm doing something wrong with `EGLContext` handling or is it just a bug with Linux EGL driver.

So, instead of create a `EGLContext` for every rendering task, I reuse previously created `EGLConext`, and just to make sure to delete all OpenGL resources at the end of every rendering task.
But, I found that even I have deleted all the OpenGL resources(I checked and I checked again), the memory usage will not drop to its initial level after a rendering task is finished. Only after I destroy the `EGLContext`, the memory will drop the its initial level.

Now, for the first method, have you guys ever encounter such crashing problem? Are the code from the nvidia post the correct way to handle `EGLContext`? Or should I do something different when it comes to create and destroy `EGLContext` rapidly.
For the second method, I learned form some posts that event you have called those OpenGL apis to delete your resources, and forced a GPU synchronous using `glFinish`, `EGLContext` may still having them in the buffer. And I think this the reason why memory usage does drop after every rendering task if I reuse 'EGLContext'. But is there a way to delete those resources immediately?

Comment: Why not simply launch an entirely new process for each request? You can even save all the trouble of cleaning up, because when a process terminates, all its allocations are cleaned up be the OS kernel anyway.

Comment: hi @datenwolf, thank your for your suggestion, I've never learned about process before, after looking into it, I think it's the right way to do things on a cloud server. I have implemented the method you suggested, will let you know how it works after some testing. Thanks again!

Comment: @datenwolf hi, sorry for the one and half year late reply. We took your advice, and thing worked out great! I will add a answer to this question to mark it the right answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We end up creating a new process for each rendering task, and things are working great! Thanks to @datenwolf !